# How use arrays in page object (PageFactory) in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: arrays, selenium, webdriver

I use Selenium Web Driver with JUnit Eclipse. I have such class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

//Path
 public class Path {
int i;
String[]path_name;
@FindBy(linkText=path_name[i])
@CacheLookup
private WebElement path;
public void path(int number,String[]path_name){
 for (i=1; i<number; i++){
    path.findElement(By.linkText(path_name[i])).click();  
 }
}
}
```

It opens defined quantity of links one by one. This class is in separate file from my main test. To call class Path I use page object (page factory).
this is code in my main test:

```
Path path=  PageFactory.initElements(driver, Path.class);
path.path ( 2, new String[]{ "First", "New text"});
```

But I get error `The value for annotation attribute FindBy.linkText must be a constant expression` on line `@FindBy(linkText=path_name[i])`. In what way I shoud declare my array as page object? Or maybe there is another way to call method path from class Path?
Error desapiared if I remove  this part of code: 
    @FindBy(linkText=path_name[i])
    @CacheLookup
But in this case JUnit could not find elements of array.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008138/selenium-webdriver-and-pagefactory-initialize-listwebelement-elements

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@FindBys` is what you're looking for. It returns a list.

If you want an array you can convert from the list or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008138/selenium-webdriver-and-pagefactory-initialize-listwebelement-elements) answear...