# WebDriver PageFactory Find Elements List

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageobjects

I have multiple elements on a page and I would like to initialize them using PageFactory.

I have tried using following

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-tree-node-leaf')]")    
    List<WebElement> allElements;
```

but this returns only one element.

now, if I use the traditional way for finding elements

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-tree-node-leaf')]"));
```

this returns 4 elements

any pointers what could be the issue?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008138/selenium-webdriver-and-pagefactory-initialize-listwebelement-elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-tree-node-leaf')]")    
List<WebElement> allElements;
```

this works. there was bug in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use **FindAll** annotation to get **series of @FindBy tags** and search for all elements that match any of the FindBy criteria.

```
@FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-tree-node-leaf')]"))
List<WebElement> allElements;
```

Comment: "how = How.XPATH" what is this part doing? i'm unable to understand

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your xpath in Chrome Developer tool or in Firebug?

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-tree-node-leaf')]"));
```

should work.

Comment: Explain the negative plz?

Comment: I assume you've got 'minus one' because your answer not really about page factory. Surely you can use instance of WebDriver directly but you are supposed not to do it with page factory.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will be more careful when reading the question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @FindBy annotation, use @FindAllBy annotation.Try this!

```
@FindAllBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-tree-node-leaf')]")    
List<WebElement> allElements;
```

Here's the [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindAllBy.java?spec=svn02cad79445b521f8ad1439e2fee80d684d935069&r=c5b6059148f72c4daeeaa78303bf21298233dcf9) for FindAllBy java class.