# Unable to locate Element when div is hidden

Tags: selenium

I have having some difficulties with some specific condition.

The page looks like the following when there is no error.

```
<script src="includes/js/errorHandling.js?v=5" type="text/javascript"/>
<div class="pmo_title">
<!--end pmo title-->
<div class="spacer2"/>
<div class="pmo-container">
```

But if any error occurs additional div class displayed.

```
<script src="includes/js/errorHandling.js?v=5" type="text/javascript"/>
<div class="pmo_title">
<!--end pmo title-->
<div class="pmo_warning">
<div class="pmo-container">
<span class="message_title">Errors :</span>
<!--display first item of list with no comma-->
<span id="fileError" class="error">File to Upload required</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="spacer2"/>
<div class="pmo-container">
```

I want to verify if I upload an invalid file and  error displayed throw an exception else continue.

I wrote the following code

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='pmo_warning']")
private WebElement errorMessage;
if (errorMessage !=null ){
throw (new IOException("file not found"));

    }

return initialize(driver, FileUpload.class);
```

It throws exception for both valid and invalid input

I have also tried

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='pmo_warning']")
private WebElement errorMessage;
if (errorMessage.IsDisplayed()){
throw (new IOException("file not found"));

    }

return initialize(driver, FileUpload.class);
```

For File without error it displays :

> Unable to locate element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `@FindAll` to get the list of `WebElement` instead and check its size as below :-

```
@FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "div.pmo_warning"))
List<WebElement> errorMessage;

if (errorMessage.size() > 0 && errorMessage.get(0).isDisplayed()){
   throw (new IOException("file not found"));
}
return initialize(driver, FileUpload.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Its works. The only problem is Find all increase the wait time.

Comment: Why do you need a FindAll annotation where you have only one FindBy. FindAll gives a OR operator for all the FindBy mentioned in the list. Look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914156/difference-between-findall-and-findbys-annotations-in-webdriver-page-factory. You can remove the FindAll and just use the List<WebElement> declaration with the single FindBy annotation.

Comment: @Grasshopper FindBy just return single WebElement, can be use instead FindAllBy as `@FindAllBy(how = How.CSS, using = "div.pmo_warning")  List<WebElement> errorMessage`.. thanks to point it out...:)

Comment: There is no @FindAllBy annotation in webdriver. It is either FindAll or FindBy or FindBys

Comment: @Grasshopper Oh may be its in earlier version, I had seen it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008138/selenium-webdriver-and-pagefactory-initialize-listwebelement-elements..:)

Answer (score 3):

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='pmo_warning']")).size() != 0